# Android - secure app data on external storage

Tags: android, security, filesystems

I need to secure my apps data securely on external data. Is there a way to hide data from getting accessed via other apps or by USB?
There is lot of data so don't want to use internal storage in private mode.
How can I set permissions on a file like chmod 700 ?

App data is PDF file which need to be opened in PDF readers. So need to take care of that also

Comment: one method could be to encrypt the files. for  hiding the source code is to use pro guard

Comment: Maybe you want this?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275311/how-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-file-in-android

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to hide data from getting accessed via other apps or by USB?

No.

> There is lot of data so don't want to use internal storage in private mode.

On most Android 3.0+ devices, internal storage and external storage are on the same partition and have the same amount of space. Hence, if a "lot of data" is too much for internal storage, it is too much for external storage, on most Android 3.0+ devices.

It is on Android 1.x/2.x where internal storage tended to be separate and a lot smaller than external storage.

> How can I set permissions on a file like chmod 700 ?

You can't.

You are welcome to use libraries like [Facebook's Conceal](https://code.facebook.com/posts/1419122541659395/introducing-conceal-efficient-storage-encryption-for-android/) to encrypt files on external storage, using a key maintained on internal storage. This has the net effect of preventing others from examining your data (except on rooted devices, of course). However, users or other apps can still delete your files.

Comment: If I use internal storage will I be able to pass intent to pdf readers to read this data?

Comment: @AbhinavTyagi: You would need to use something [like `FileProvider`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) for that. Of course, you would need a similar sort of `ContentProvider` to decrypt Conceal'd files as well.