# Secured folder in memory

Tags: android

How is it possible to secure all the content downloaded by application? We need these files to be available only for this single app and can't be copied/viewed by any other app or by USB cable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep your files in internal memory. Try the following code

```
File myFolder = context.getDir("DirectoryName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); //Create folder in internal memory;
File myFile = new File(myFolder, "fileName"); //Create file inside the folder.
FileOutputStream ouStreamt = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
```

Use the ouStreamt to write your content into the file. Hope this will help you

Answer (score 1):

Referring to the documentation http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

*By default, files saved to the internal storage are private to your application and other applications cannot access them (nor can the user).*

Answer (score 1):

You can implement file encrytion\dercyption if it's really needed - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275311/how-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-file-in-android). But in most cases internal storage would be secure enough.