# Encrypt android database , dont working (apparently)

Tags: android, sqlite, encryption

I do all [process to encrypt database of android](http://www.greenbot.com/article/2145380/why-and-how-to-encrypt-your-android-device.html):
Setting>security>Encrypt phone

Then i try get my database of android

```
$ adb shell
$ run-as com.your.package cat /data/data/com.your.package/databases/your_db > /storage/sdcard0/Download/your.db
```

and result is all of my data are not encrypt....

i do another test and reeinstal my app, and get my database again, all data stay uncrypted...

what i need to do, to encrypt my database (without code), and how i can check this data encrypted?

---edited---

if i test encrypt with this code, i get return "true", but i still can acess the .db and read all information...

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public static boolean isEncrypted(Context context) {
        DevicePolicyManager devicePolicyManager = (DevicePolicyManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            int status = devicePolicyManager.getStorageEncryptionStatus();
            if (DevicePolicyManager.ENCRYPTION_STATUS_ACTIVE == status) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/security/encryption/):

> Once a device is encrypted, all user-created data is automatically
>   encrypted before committing it to disk and all reads automatically
>   decrypt data before returning it to the calling process.

And from the article you mention on your question:

> So even if someone pulls all the data off your phone, circumventing
>   the lock screen, the data will be useless without your key.

So, your data is encrypted while it's on your phone and protected by your lock (for example a PIN lock).

When you connect the device to a computer via USB, as long as you have entered your PIN correctly, the operation is considered safe and your data will be decrypted before it's sent to your computer.

Comment: i need prove my database are encrypted, how i can do dat?

Comment: If the encryption of your files is critical for your application you may want to encrypt/decrypt the database file when you need to use it. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275311/how-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-file-in-android