# Backup sqlite to external storage and make it unaccesible/encrypt it on Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have found examples on how to backup and restore and app's sqlite database from the external storage.

Since the file is a sqlite database, copying it to a computer and using a sqlite browser app, allows to view its content.

My question is: is there a way to do something with the database backup file in order to not have it accessible to other apps?

Comment: If you are developing a new app, I suggest to use GreenDAO as your ORM which supports SQLCipher  (SQLite encryption). It will encrypt the entire database and it's actually easy to use.
http://greenrobot.org/greendao/documentation/database-encryption

Comment: Thank you Arman, but the app is already made.

Comment: Well, then all you have to do is a simple encryption/decription :
http://stackoverflow.com/a/8041442/1420189