# How to know which finger is scanned for bio-metric?

Tags: android, biometrics, android-fingerprint-api

My requirement is to scan the finger and based on the finger I've to navigate user to the particular page in android

**Explanation**

While registering user will give different fingerprints for different functionalities

*Ex:*

1. For navigating to login page user may use left index finger
2. For navigating to About us page user may use right index finger

for each fingerprint I've to redirect to the different pages based on the user wish. For this I've checked these [link1](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-FingerprintDialog/issues/20), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44520343/android-how-to-get-unique-key-from-finger-print-authentication) and many more but I'm unable to achieve it. Can any one give suggestion...

Comment: The [Fingerprint API](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0#fingerprint-authentication) doesn't work that way. It only lets you know if the fingerprint being scanned is registered on the phone for authentication purposes, and no further information about which finger was used.

Comment: Thnq Michael, do you have any idea to trigger if any new fingerprint is added. I've tried with KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException but it's not triggering

Comment: As far as I'm aware Android doesn't announce when a new fingerprint is added. You can only query a fingerprint currently on the scanner against the database of existing saved fingerprints.

Comment: @MichaelDodd Thnk you :-)

Comment: I've found an alternative that may be of use. See my updated answer.

Comment: @MichaelDodd Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're asking for isn't possible, at least not using Android's Fingerprint API. The [`FingerprintManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/fingerprint/FingerprintManager) class acts as a way of accessing previously-stored fingerprints within the [Android keystore system](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore)

> User authentication authorizes a specific cryptographic operation associated with one key. In this mode, each operation involving such a key must be individually authorized by the user. Currently, the only means of such authorization is fingerprint authentication: [`FingerprintManager.authenticate`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/fingerprint/FingerprintManager.html#authenticate(android.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManager.CryptoObject,%20android.os.CancellationSignal,%20int,%20android.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManager.AuthenticationCallback,%20android.os.Handler)). Such keys can only be generated or imported if at least one fingerprint is enrolled (see [`FingerprintManager.hasEnrolledFingerprints`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/fingerprint/FingerprintManager.html#hasEnrolledFingerprints())). These keys become permanently invalidated once a new fingerprint is enrolled or all fingerprints are unenrolled.

The [`FingerprintManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/fingerprint/FingerprintManager) class itself  only has one authentication method, [`authenticate()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/fingerprint/FingerprintManager.html#authenticate(android.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManager.CryptoObject,%20android.os.CancellationSignal,%20int,%20android.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManager.AuthenticationCallback,%20android.os.Handler)), which determined if the scanned fingerprint is known to the device. In API 28 this is deprecated in favour of [`BiometricPrompt`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/biometrics/BiometricPrompt), which does pretty much the same job.

So in short, no. You'd need to use an exteral fingerprint scanner and roll your own solution based on the functionality the external hardware provides.

**EDIT** As an alternative option, you can detect swipes on the Fingerprint Sensor using [`FingerprintGestureController`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/FingerprintGestureController), but again, this doesn't detect which finger is being used on the sensor.