# React Native : How to create text file and save it to external storage

Tags: react-native

I am trying to create a text file using react native for both Android and iOS device. How can we store the string data in text file and and save it to external storage of device. Please suggest if any library for the same.

Comment: Check out [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs) library.

Comment: You need to encrypt that file. Android providing Chrio class for encryption/decryption here is the link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275311/how-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-file-in-android

Answer (score 15):

Use npm package `react-native-fs` for it..!

Install :

```
npm i react-native-fs
```

Creating File Example :

```
var RNFS = require('react-native-fs');
 
var path = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/test.txt';
 
// write the file
RNFS.writeFile(path, 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'utf8')
  .then((success) => {
    console.log('FILE WRITTEN!');
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err.message);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks Praz for your help. I have checked with code and getting the log of FILE WRITTEN. But I am able to view the file in my android device. Please help