# Create and save text file in React Native on web platform produce RNFSFileTypeRegular

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I am having an issue using React Native project created by expo to create and save some string to text file. I tried it using Filesystem by expo but its not working on web platform.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native : How to create text file and save it to external storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53701424/react-native-how-to-create-text-file-and-save-it-to-external-storage)

Comment: TypeError: Unable to get property 'RNFSFileTypeRegular' of undefined or null reference.
This error show up.

Comment: I think react-native-fs does not yet have support for the web platform:
https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs/issues/551