# Getting Exception java.security.InvalidKeyException: Invalid AES key length: 29 bytes?

Tags: java, encryption, aes

When running below programme i am getting this  exception. Not able to figure out what the issue as AES allows the 128 -256 bit key?

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.security.InvalidKeyException: Invalid AES key length: 29 bytes
at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineGetKeySize(DashoA13*..)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.b(DashoA13*..)
```

Getting exception at line 20

**Here is the programme**

```
 import java.security.Key;

 import javax.crypto.Cipher;
 import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

 import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;
 import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;

 public class AESEncryptionDecryptionTest {

   private static final String ALGORITHM       = "AES";
   private static final String myEncryptionKey = "ThisIsSecurityKey";
   private static final String UNICODE_FORMAT  = "UTF8";

   public static String encrypt(String valueToEnc) throws Exception {
 Key key = generateKey();
 Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
 c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);  //////////LINE 20
 byte[] encValue = c.doFinal(valueToEnc.getBytes());
 String encryptedValue = new BASE64Encoder().encode(encValue);
 return encryptedValue;
   }

public static String decrypt(String encryptedValue) throws Exception {
Key key = generateKey();
Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
byte[] decordedValue = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(encryptedValue);
byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decordedValue);
String decryptedValue = new String(decValue);
return decryptedValue;
}

private static Key generateKey() throws Exception {
byte[] keyAsBytes;
keyAsBytes = myEncryptionKey.getBytes(UNICODE_FORMAT);
Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyAsBytes, ALGORITHM);
return key;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

String value = "password1";
String valueEnc = AESEncryptionDecryptionTest.encrypt(value);
String valueDec = AESEncryptionDecryptionTest.decrypt(valueEnc);

System.out.println("Plain Text : " + value);
System.out.println("Encrypted : " + valueEnc);
System.out.println("Decrypted : " + valueDec);
}

}
```

Comment: which statement generates the exception?

Comment: c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

Answer (score 32, accepted):

AES allows 128, 192 or 256 bit key length. That is 16, 24 or 32 byte. Try taking just the first 16 bytes of your `mEncryptionKey` as the `keyAsBytes`.

**Edit:**
An after though occurred to me. A habit I have formed, and one which I recommend, is to take a SHA hash of a password/passphrase, and use that as the source bytes of your key. Taking a hash guarantees the key data will be the correct size, irrespective of the length of the password/passphrase. Your current implementation of using the String bytes has two problems;

- It will break your key generation if someone uses a short password.
- Two different passwords for which the first 16 bytes are the same will create the same key.

Both of these problems are eliminated by using a hash.

Take a look at the `buildKey()` method in this class; https://github.com/qwerky/DataVault/blob/master/src/qwerky/tools/datavault/DataVault.java

Comment: Thanks Qwerky. Some more findings.When i give myEncryptionKey  as 16 character long i.e 128 bit length this program run fines but when i give it as 24 charecter long(192 bit length) or 32 character long(256 bit length ) then i get the error as "Illegal key size or default parameters". Can i set the  key length to 256  or 192 if i want?

Comment: To use 192 or 256 you may need to enable "unlimited key strength" policy files. This is due to a legal restriction in the United States. See here; http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Security/AES/AES_v1.html. Search `Illegal key size or default parameters` on this site, there are several questions and answers about it.

Comment: In your example in Datavault.java, BouncyCastleProvider is used which is not standard java class. Due to some restrictions i need to go only with standar java classes. Can i use some other implementation of provider class instaed of BouncyCastleProvider in the example you hav epointed out?

Comment: If the goal is to make the key based on some input like user's password, hashing is good but PBKDF2 is better. If possible, use per-key random salt and save it for next time you use the same key. If that's not possible, try to use some per-user unique data (e.g. username) as salt. This helps protect you against rainbow table attacks. See here for an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375541/password-verification-with-pbkdf2-in-java

Comment: Actually, I'm getting `java.security.InvalidKeyException: Invalid key length: 32 bytes` for SHA.

Comment: @TomášZato: Do you have "unlimited key strength" enabled? See Qwerky's comment about 256-bit key length.

Comment: I'm not convinced that using a hash of a password is cryptographically secure enough, although it's probably not much worse than using the password itself. But I think nowadays, if you have to make a secret key from a password, the recommended way is to use something like `new PBEKeySpec(password, salt, 10000, 256)`;

Answer (score 1):

The key uses randomness as input, but there are stiill requirements for how it is composed. The `SecretKeySpec` constructor you used is for loading an already generated key into memory. Instead, use [`KeyGenerator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/crypto/KeyGenerator.html).

```
KeyGenerator kg = KeyGenerator.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
kg.init(128);
SecretKey k = kg.generateKey();
```

Also note that AES-128 is now actually thought to be weaker than AES-256. It probably isn't drastically different but the benefit from the longer key size may be outweighed by simplifications elsewhere (fewer rounds).

Comment: Hi John. I want to to use the self assigned key as i will  be using as shared key. I want to use the key which is known and asiigned by me not system generated key. Can you throw some inputs how i can use the self assigned key of any length less than 256 bit in AES?